# Pythons win32gui module: find ALL windows

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32gui

I'm using the following callback function to get all top level windows including their child windows:

```
def mycallback(hwnd, data):
    data[win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)] = hwnd
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, mycallback, data)
    return True
mywindows = {}
win32gui.EnumWindows(mycallback, mywindows)
```

That piece of code returns a huge dictionary of window handles. One of those handles is 788292, which is Notepad++. Then I search for the children of Notepad++/788292 via `win32gui.EnumChildWindows` on a separate console. That is how I notice the window handle 853784 whose name is "Edit".

However that window handle does not appear in my huge dictionary mentioned earlier. Why not?

Comment: Is the window handle specific to "EDIT" not listed? I use C++ to test these two functions by enumerating all the windows and enumerating all the child windows of "Notepad++" separately. Compare the child windows of "Notepad++", which return the same number of child windows.

Comment: By the way, I am testing your code in python and will return `pywintypes.error: (126, 'EnumChildWindows', 'The specified module could not be found.')`. I am still researching the specific cause of the error. This is why I switched to C++ testing.

Comment: I've retested the issue. This time it's a little bit different but in principle the same. This is the Notepad++/EnumChildWindows dictionary on a separate console (same callback as above): {'#32770': 66908, 'Button': 66922, 'Static': 66924, 'SysTabControl32': 132272, 'Scintilla': 132276, 'splitterContainer': 263444, 'wespliter': 328982, 'msctls_statusbar32': 394476, 'dockingManager': 394474, 'wedockspliter': 132328, 'nsdockspliter': 132336, 'ReBarWindow32': 66906, 'ToolbarWindow32': 66902, 'Edit': 66914}. Some of these windows are not contained in "mywindows"/EnumWindows, e.g. 66908, 66922...

Comment: Have you tested in C++? You need to determine if this is specific to python.

Comment: ohhh I have found the reason: there are MULTIPLE windows which return the same win32gui.GetClassName value :-) Hence some windows are overwritten in the dictionary. How embarassing, I should have noticed that, since it's "getCLASSname" ... sorry. I've just noticed it, because my Notepad++ Edit window had disappeared after I had started windows-notepad (which also has an Edit window)

Comment: All right, I test it in C++ , I don't add GetClassName to do more research.The detail  may be the reason that I not notice.

Answer (score 0):

this will get all windows and also background windows

```
def getAllwindows():
   windows = []
   for i in range(10000000):
      text = win32gui.GetWindowText(i)
      if text == "":
           continue
      windows.append(text)
   return list(set(windows))
print(getAllwindows())
```

Comment: That doesn't seem too optimal of a solution with a 10 million loop.